# Command Prompt DNS lookup

Tags: windows, dns, command-prompt

I have this homework assignment for my Data Communications & Networking class and I am completely lost.

It is about learning DNS lookup using the Command prompt but my professor didn't really explain it very well at all.

[image: dns_lookup]

On the left is me typing the line into command prompt (as administrator) & on the right is the example the professor gave us. Every time I use -type=NS, it returns root as opposed to what the professor was getting on the right.

I do not understand this stuff at all so all of my Google searches are coming up empty and I'm 2 hours into this now and completely confused. Can anyone explain how I can end up with a result like the one he is getting on the right?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet? The lookup needs to go to the internet

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to the internet. I was first on Wi-Fi then I plugged in my ethernet cable and the same deal both times. I'm typing this on the same computer so that's proof I'm connected to the internet lol

Comment: hmm. Is the internet access direct or via proxy? Try typing nslookup mit.edu and see if it resolves. It seems that the professor is behind mit network and specifying the Name Server to be mit.edu. But on your home PC the NS will be the DNS of your ISP or OpenDNS if you have configured for it

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that question. I'm on my home network with Comcast... And I typed in what you said and I get "Server: www Address: 10.1.10.1    Non-authoritative answer: Name: mit.edu Address: 23.202.254.127"

Comment: So the name is resolving. mit.edu is 23.202.254.127. It seems that Comcast sets up a local proxy server which is 10.1.0.1 (10. is private)

Comment: It seems nslookup -type NS Mit.Edu means use NSLookup to look up for records of type Name Server. Now if I understand it correctly the Prof asked NSLookup to give all name servers for Mit.Edu. Now mostly since he was on Mit network, that was possible, but since you are on the internet, you will not get that information. You will need to be on a network with Name servers setup to make that work. (not your home network) See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your DNS server is setup wrong**. Try setting it right.

Here is the link to setup Google DNS server for Windows: [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). See section named Microsoft Windows in this page.

Comment: I followed these steps. This is resulting in "Server: UnKnown Address: 2001:4860:4860::8888 DNS request timed out. timeout was 2 seconds DNS request timed out. timeout was 2 seconds *** Request to UnKnown timed-out"

Comment: Set IPv4 address: 8.8.8.8. And only set one IPv4 address for now.

Comment: Ah you hit it right on the nail! I unchecked IPV 6 from my Ethernet Properties and the requests were sent through 8.8.8.8 and I am now getting the correct results! I would upvote you but I don't have enough reputation yet. Thank you so much, you saved me!